# How to use `\@ifdefinable{xfoo}{...}` when `\foo` is already defined?

Tags: conditionals

The following code fails to compile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\foo}{xyzzy}

\@ifdefinable{xfoo}{\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

More precisely, it fails with the following error:

```
LaTeX Error: Command \foo already defined.
Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

This is essentially because of the way `\@ifdefinable` is implemented internally.

**Question.** Is there a good workaround that doesn't involve renaming `\foo` or replacing `\@ifdefinable` with a different command? (In my actual situation, `\foo` is provided by one package and `\@ifdefinable` is being used by another package.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument to `\@ifdefinable` should be a control sequence, not a string of characters. The error is spurious due to the fact that `\@ifdefinable` strips of the first character in the stringified form of the argument, assuming it's a backslash.

So you should do

```
\@ifdefinable{\xfoo}{...}
```

You're perhaps confusing this with `\@ifundefined`: if you want to see if `\foo` is undefined (or `\relax`) the test is

```
\@ifundefined{foo}{code for undefined}{code for defined}
```

---

This is indeed a bug in `aliasctr.sty`, where line 59 is

```
 59       \@ifdefinable{c@#1}{%
```

and it should be

```
 59       \expandafter\@ifdefinable\csname c@#1\endcsname{%
```

Comment: That explains why the first character goes missing. The erroneous invocation is not mine, though – it comes from the definition of `\@counteralias` (in `aliasctr.sty` of the `thmtools` package).

Comment: @ZhenLin Sorry, bug in the package!